# integromat - (make) replace multible strings

Tags: string, makefile, make.com

please help:

I want to replace multible strings in Make

if the string is a than replace with 1
if the string is b than replace with 2
if the string is c than replace with 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCEZG.png)

how can i do this?

Thanks a lot!

Grettings Fabian

google, search
testing vor 3 hours

Comment: Please don't post images to StackOverflow.  Edit the question and cut and paste the text into your question, formatting it properly as a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
{{replace(replace("Testabc"; "a"; "1")), "b"; "2"}}
```